# TOP command combined with printf

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, top, printf

I have a simple while true statement:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    printf -- '-%.0s' {1..100}; echo "" | top -l 1 >> file.txt
    sleep 10
done
```

The issue I am facing is that the `printf` statement is only outputting to console instead of within the file.

The desired outcome of my command is to have the top command output to a file with a --- separator between each new top. Like so:

```
----------------
top output
---------------
top output
etc...
```

I have also tried:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    (
    printf -- '-%.0s' {1..100}; echo ""
    top -l 1
    ) >> file.txt
    sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    printf -- '-%.0s' {1..100} >> file.txt 
    echo "" >> file.txt
    top -l 1 >> file.txt
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Thanks for the quick help.